# class array, cast pointer in operator[]

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, casting, operator-overloading

In my library I've an array class:

```
template < class Type >
class Array
{ 
Type* array_cData;
...
Type& operator[] (llint Index)
    {
        if (Index >= 0 && Index < array_iCount && Exist())
            return array_cData[Index];
    } 
};
```

And that's nice, but if I've generated in the stack the class like:

```
Array<NString>* space = new Array<NString>(strList->toArray());
checkup("NString split", (*space)[0] == "Hello" && (*space)[1] == "world");
//I must get the object pointed by space and after use the operator[]
```

So my question is: I can get the object in array_cData without specify object pointed like this:

```
Array<NString>* space = new Array<NString>(strList->toArray());
checkup("NString split", space[0] == "Hello" && space[1] == "world");
```

Thanks in advance! :3

-Nobel3D

Comment: Sure, just use an automatic variable: `Array<NString> space(strList->toArray());`. Even better just use `std::array`.

Comment: @Jarod42 strList->toArray()  return a Array<NString>, I know it will be better when function return Array<NString>*, I had in mind to improved -Nobel3D

Comment: The fact that it returns `Array<NString>` seems better that by pointer, but do you need pointer ?

Comment: Yes, I wanna just call 'space[0]' when user call operator, when the 'space' is a pointer -Nobel3D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idiomatic way is to not have pointer:

```
Array<NString> space{strList->toArray()};
checkup("NString split", space[0] == "Hello" && space[1] == "world");
```

with pointer, you have to dereference it in some way

```
Array<NString> spacePtr = // ...
spacePtr->operator[](0); // classical for non operator method
(*spacePtr)[0]; // classical for operator method
spacePtr[0][0]; // abuse of the fact that a[0] is *(a + 0)

 auto& spaceRef = *spacePtr;
 spaceRef[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is to convert the pointer to a reference

```
Array<NString>* spaceptr = new Array<NString>(strList->toArray());

Array<NString> &space=*spaceptr;

checkup("NString split", space[0] == "Hello" && space[1] == "world");
```

P.S. if `operator[]` receives an invalid index value, you will get an dose of undefined behavior, and a second helping of a crash.

Comment: The goal is automate this process when user call operator[] -Nobel3D